# Firebase FIRStorageErrorDomain Codes=-13021 Error when Fetching Images for iOS Application

Tags: ios, firebase, authorization, firebase-storage

I am creating an iOS app that allows users to login using their phone numbers (powered by Firebase) and it also fetches images that are stored in Firebase's Storage. An issue that I am running into is that occasionally after I don't use the app for a while but I have stayed logged in, when it tries to fetch images from the Firebase Storage it gets the error:
`FIRStorageErrorDomain Codes=-13021 User does not have permissions to access "ImageLink"`

`error: { "code": 403, "message": "permission denied. Could not perform this operation"`

I know this has to do with my Firebase Rules which are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried removing the `if` statement and it works, but obviously I don't want to compromise my security for stored images. The issue I am having is I don't understand how the `auth.uid` is being stored/sent and whether this issue is because it is expiring or something?
A standard fetch operation in my code looks like:

```
//function to actually grab the designated image from Firebase, synchronously
//returns a UIImageView
func grabImage(_ photoLink: String, _ completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
    //keep a reference to storage
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    // Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
    let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: photoLink)
    //return the image to be attached to the card views
    storageRef.getData(maxSize: 40 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //Error occurred fetching image
            print("Failed to fetch image in grabImage!", error!)
            //appear that its still fetching on error
            completion(UIImage.gif(name: "imageLoading")!)
        } else {
            //add this latest image to the resImages result array
            completion(UIImage(data: data!)!)
        }
    }
}
```

I am a bit confused by how this works in terms of how the Auth.uid is being sent and what can I do to ensure that auth.uid isn't null, and what steps I can take to prevent users from getting this error.